# Presto-CLI java.net.SocketException: Connection refused in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, presto, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created dataproc cluster using beta version of gcloud with optional component presto.

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create presto-test --optional-components=PRESTO --image-version=1.3-deb9
```

When I try to execute below command to access hive catalog it could successfully open the presto-cli.

```
./presto \
    --server presto-cluster-m-0:8080 \
    --socks-proxy localhost:1080 \
    --catalog hive \
    --schema default
```

But I am getting below error while querying through presto-cli.

> presto:default> show tables;
>
> Error running command: java.net.SocketException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Any help in this will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

A couple of minor fixes to your connection settings may be necessary.

- Presto runs on port 8060 when running as an optional component
- Your cluster creation command did not create your cluster in HA mode, so the hostname of the master is just -m, not -m-0

Assuming your cluster is named presto-test, then the command should look like

```
./presto \
--server presto-test-m:8060 \
--socks-proxy localhost:1080 \
--catalog hive \
--schema default
```

If that doesn't work, you might want to double check that the socks proxy and Presto are running correctly.

1. Run `curl -I -x socks5h://localhost:1080 presto-test-m:8088` - it should return HTTP 302. If you get a connection refused error or host not found error, your socks proxy is not working correctly.
2. Run `gcloud beta dataproc clusters describe presto-test` and check that the following lines appear in the output

   ```
   softwareConfig:
     optionalComponents:
     - PRESTO
   ```
3. Ssh into the master node of your Presto cluster and run `which presto` and `sudo systemctl status presto` to verify that Presto is installed and running.

There is a known issue where Presto may fail to be installed when specified as an optional component (in which case steps 2 and 3 above would show that Presto is not activated on the cluster). This should be fixed in the next Dataproc release - if you're running into this issue now, try using this command to create the cluster instead:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create presto-test --properties dataproc:dataproc.components.activate=presto --image-version=1.3-deb9
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried above options but still facing issue. Presto installation seems proper, but there is some issue with the connection. I have tried "curl -I -x socks5h://localhost:1080 presto-test-m:8086" but it returned connection error.  I tried using presto from presto server itself but facing "Error running command: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080". Please suggest.

Comment: Can you try recreating the cluster using the PRESTO flag?

`gcloud beta dataproc clusters create presto-test --optional-components=PRESTO --image-version=1.3-deb9`

Dataproc has fixed the issue with Presto not being installed this week, so this should correctly activate Presto.

Comment: If you're trying to use Presto directly from the server, you still need to specify the correct port 8060 (`presto --server localhost:8060`)